# WhatsApp NSURL returning nil When sharing text - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I'm trying to share text with WhatsApp but the NSURL is always returning nil but the text is encoded right ! take a look at my code :

```
var msg : NSString = "to the world of none";
var titlewithoutspace = msg.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var urlWhats = NSString(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(titlewithoutspace)")
println(urlWhats)
var whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlWhats as String)
println(whatsappURL)
```

when i am printing the result the string is equal to :

```
whatsapp://send?text=Optional("to%20the%20world%20of%20none")
```

and the whatsappURL returning always nil :

```
nil
```

Comment: for 5 mins I was wondering from where `Optional ` comes in your output string?

Comment: Yeah, i thought about it too ! :)

Comment: check Sulthan answer.. it will help you...

Comment: it both does right, if i could give them two correct answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` returns an optional `String` that's why `urlWhats` contains `Optional("")`. To avoid this you just need to unwrap the optional like this :

```
var msg: NSString = "to the world of none";
var titlewithoutspace = msg.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if let titlewithoutspace = titlewithoutspace {
    var urlWhats = NSString(string: "whatsapp://send?text=\(titlewithoutspace)")
    var whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlWhats as String)
    println(whatsappURL)
} else {
    // Unwrapping failed because titlewithoutspace is nil (might be because stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding failed).
}
```

Besides I suggest you to use String type directly since `NSString` is useless to you there (except for `stringByAdding…`) :

```
var msg: NSString = "to the world of none";
var titlewithoutspace = msg.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
if let titlewithoutspace = titlewithoutspace {
    var urlWhats = "whatsapp://send?text=\(titlewithoutspace)"
    var whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlWhats)
    println(whatsappURL)
} else {
    // Unwrapping failed because titlewithoutspace is nil (might be because stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding failed).
}
```

Also please note that `NSURL(string:)` may fail so it also returns an optional `NSURL` object. To use it you might need to unwrap it as well as I did for `titlewithoutspace`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\(...)` should be reserved for writing into console. As you can see, it adds `Optional(....)` around your string and that's not valid to be in an URL.

Either force it to unwrap `"whatsapp://send?text=\(titlewithoutspace!)"` or better, use

```
String(format: "whatsapp://send?text=%@", titlewithoutspace)
```

Comment: String interpolation can be used safely, why would it be reserved to console writing ಠ_ಠ ?

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.0/2.1

```
func openURL(urlString: String, message: String) {
    var formattedURL: String = urlString

    if let strippedMessage = message.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) {
        formattedURL = "\(urlString)\(strippedMessage)"
    }

    if let url = NSURL(string: formattedURL) as NSURL? {
        print(url)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a tested Sharing code in swift**

```
let url  = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fin%2Fapp%2Fwhatsapp-messenger%2Fid310633997%3Fmt%3D8")

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
 }
 else {
      let errorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Cannot Send Message", message: "Your device is not able to send WhatsApp messages.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
      errorAlert.show()
      }
```

**Note : You just need to convert your url to encode format**

Comment: i just give reference.. i remove if you think like this

Comment: Thank you for editing. It's much better without the link. :)